# Можно ли загрузить содержимое модулей пакета, если __init__ пуст?

Tags: python, python-import

К примеру есть пакет pkg с неизвестным содержимым и пустым `__init__.py`. Нужно загрузить содержимое модулей пакета командой типа

```
from pkg import *
```

с целью получить в dir() список функций из модулей пакета. Есть ли стандартные средства или нужно "вручную" перебирать пакет и загружать модули по отдельности?

Необходимо это с целью получить из модулей пакета все функции с именем типа foo_some_function(), при этом содержимое пакета заранее неизвестно

Comment: "Неизвестное содержимое" это что? `__init__` это что, может быть файл с расширением *.py?

Comment: @sys_dev да, вы правы насчет init. Под неизвестным содержимым я понимаю неизвестный набор py-модулей с допуститмыми именами.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем случае, чтобы узнать можно ли проимпортировать `a.b.c`, нужно проимпортировать `a.b.c`—более короткого пути нет, например:

```
import os.path
from plumbum.cmd import grep
from macropy.case_classes import macros, case
from github.username.repo import module
from quickdraw import fillcircle
```

Пример реализации: [`quickdraw.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/a011754fa77737e099b7#file-quickdraw-py-L50).

В частном (но распространённом) случае, [можно `pkgutil` использовать, чтобы найти все модули для заданного Питон пакета](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1707709/4279): `pkgutil.iter_modules()` перечисляет прямых детей, а `pkgutil.walk_packages()` всё дерево позволяет обойти.

Comment: В дополнение - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707709/list-all-the-modules-that-are-part-of-a-python-package/1707786#1707786