# Динамическое подключение модуля при наличии функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Есть каталог с файлами расширения ".py". Необходимо пробежаться по файлам и подключить только те, в которых имеется функция с определённым названием.

Дошёл только до этого (файл main.py):

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import importlib

filepath = './'
for f in listdir(filepath):
    if isfile(join(filepath, f)) and f != 'main.py':
        moduleloader = importlib.find_loader(f.split('.')[0])
        if moduleloader is not None:
            # check if module has function
```

До места с комментарием доходит, но как сделать проверку - вопрос. И ещё вопрос, как дальше эту функцию использовать?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Можно ли загрузить содержимое модулей пакета, если `__init__` пуст?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/518371/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы загрузить все модули по заданному пути можно использовать [`pkgutil.iter_modules(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules). Преимущество по сравнению с вариантом, основанным на `glob('*.py')`, в том что поддерживаются и другие форматы модулей (zip-архивы, директории, если это желаемо). Например, чтобы вызывать функцию `g` из всех модулей, расположенных в `modules` директории, исключая Питон-пакеты и текущий модуль:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import inspect
import pkgutil

for module_finder, name, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(path=['modules']):
    if ispkg or name == __name__:
        continue # skip packages or itself
    mod = module_finder.find_module(name).load_module(name)
    g = next((f for funcname, f in inspect.getmembers(mod, inspect.isfunction)
              if funcname == 'g'), None) # find *g* function in the *mod* module
    if g is None:
        print('no g function in {} module'.format(name))
    else: # call it
        g()
```

Для поиска функций в модуле используется `inspect.getmembers()` c [`inspect.isfunction` предикатом](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction). Достоинство по сравнению с `hasattr()` в том, что только функции будут найдены, а другие объекты такие как строки, классы игнорируются. Обратите внимание: класс является callable в Питоне—если `C` класс, то `C()` может работать, но `inspect.isfunction(C)` возвращает `False`—если в вашем случае нужен другой результат, используйте другой предикат вместо `inspect.isfunction()`.

Если путь относительный (такой как `modules`), то он (как обычно) задаётся относительно [текущей рабочей директории, которая может отличаться от директории со скриптом, исполняющим код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044).

Обратите внимание, что при импортировании модуля, выполняется код на уровне модуля. Это может быть произвольный код. Не импортируйте модули, содержимое которых, вы не контролируете.

Подумайте об использовании уже существующих инструментов таких как `unittest`, `py.test`, чтобы запускать тесты (если ваши модули содержат тесты), или `yapsy` пакет по работе с плагинами, или [`setuptools`' "entry points", известные по их конфигурации в `setup.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14579111/4279) (если ваши требования близки к функциональности, которую эти библиотеки представляет)—[нет нужды изобретать велосипед одно требование за раз](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932072/4279).

Comment: Порой пробежаться по велосипедам полезно) Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

```
import importlib
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, splitext

for f in listdir(filepath):
    if isfile(join(filepath, f)) and f != 'main.py':
        module_name, _ = splitext(f)
        m = importlib.import_module(module_name)
        if hasattr(m, 'function_name'):
            function_name = getattr(m, 'function_name')
            function_name()
```

Comment: Лишний раз убеждаюсь, что для Python ларчик всегда открывается просто) Спасибо!

Comment: @AccumPlus: `importlib.import_module(module_name)` не обязан импортировать `{filepath}/{module_name}.py`. Например, если `filepath` не в `sys.path`, то он либо не найдёт `module_name` либо (хуже) какой-нибудь другой модуль попытается проимпортировать. В вашем случае это случайно работает, потому что при запуске `main.py` его директория автоматически в pythonpath добавляется и модули в той же директории лежат. Можно [использовать `pkgutil.iter_modules()` вместо этого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571140/23044)

Answer (score 1):

```
import os, sys, itertools

def get_modules(fn_names: [str], folder: str) -> dict:
    sys.path.append(folder)  # путь поиска модуля
    def get():
        for file in os.listdir(folder):  # файлы+каталоги из folder
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, file)):  # только файлы
                name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
                if ext == '.py':  # расширения ".py"
                    module = __import__(name)  # локальный импорт модуля
                    for fn in fn_names:  # если несколько названий функций
                        if hasattr(module, fn):  # функция с определённым названием
                            yield fn, module  # вернуть модуль функции
    modules = {}  # {функ1:[модуль1,..], функ2:[..],..}
    for f, m in get():
        try: modules[f].append(m)
        except KeyError: modules[f] = [m]
    return modules

if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder = '_Tmpc9'

    def test_files_creator(dt: {int: [int]}):
        '''создать файлы модулей и записать функции'''
        md = 'module_{}.py'
        fn = '''def fn_{0}(arg): print("call %s( %s ) ~ %s" % (fn_{0}.__name__, arg, sys.modules[__name__]))'''
        if not os.path.isdir(folder): os.makedirs(folder)
        for m in dt:
            j = os.path.join(folder, md.format(m))
            print('import sys\n', file=open(j, 'w'))
            for f in dt[m]: print(fn.format(f), file=open(j, 'a'))

    test_files_creator({1: [1, 2], 2: [1, 2], 3: [2]})

    ms = get_modules(fn_names=['fn_1', 'fn_2'], folder=folder)

    print('\n'.join('{}:{}<{} module'.format(k, [m.__name__ for m in v], len(v))
                    for k, v in ms.items()))
    print()

    m = ms['fn_1'][0]
    print(m)
    getattr(m, 'fn_1')('one')

    # имя модуля и функции можно использовать как если бы был обычный import:
    # динамическое подключение модуля
    globals().update({m.__name__: m for m in set(itertools.chain(*ms.values()))})
    print(module_2)
    module_2.fn_1('two')

    # динамическое подключение функции
    m = ms['fn_2'][2]
    globals()['fn_2'] = getattr(m, 'fn_2')
    print(m)
    fn_2('three')
```

out:

```
fn_1:['module_1', 'module_2']<2 module
fn_2:['module_1', 'module_2', 'module_3']<3 module

<module 'module_1' from '_Tmpc9\\module_1.py'>
call fn_1( one ) ~ <module 'module_1' from '_Tmpc9\\module_1.py'>
<module 'module_2' from '_Tmpc9\\module_2.py'>
call fn_1( two ) ~ <module 'module_2' from '_Tmpc9\\module_2.py'>
<module 'module_3' from '_Tmpc9\\module_3.py'>
call fn_2( three ) ~ <module 'module_3' from '_Tmpc9\\module_3.py'>
```