# ООП в Python - стоит ли избегать констант и обычных функций?

Tags: python, ооп

Если писать программу в ООП стиле на Python, то стоит ли полностью углубляться в ОПП, избегая констант (не синглтонов) и обычных функций (не методов) или следует комбинировать ?

Задача из реальной жизни: мне надо на фреймворке `Flask` построить небольшой, но расширяемый сервис. 
Что я делаю:

1. Делаю файл с роутами (распределением) урлов.
2. Делаю модуль `handlers` в который складываю все обработчики роутов. Они представляются в виде классов, т.к. это позволяет воспользоваться наследованием и прочими ООП инструментами.
3. Понятное дело, модуль models, который содержит представление базы данных.
4. Небольшой модуль, в котором я соединяю роуты с обработчиками этих роутов. Так же тут я могу задать какие-то общие настройки для обработчиком, например, логирование.

Так вот, разве это не лучше, чем написать кучу функций, которые и принимают запрос, и сразу занимаются обработкой этого запроса ? И если есть более оптимальные и гибкий способ сделать это, не могли бы вы его подсказать ?

Comment: во-во. когда привыкаешь писать на других языках в ооп стиле (интерфейсами и прокидыванием зависимостей, то есть контрактами), то в питоне получается ступор где код сам вытягивает на себя зависимости.

Comment: @vitidev с кем-то я уже обсуждал, что не надо Java в Питоне писать. Мысль эта не новая, люди десятилетия назад ещё пытались Fortran   в  тогда новых сегодня уже забытых языках писать. Какие-то вещи универсальны, какие-то вещи специфичны для языка—нужно менять привычки при переключении языка. Лучше не думать как стиль программирования обозвать, а подумать насколько читаем будет код для людей знакомых с Питоном (или для вас же через полгода когда детали позабудутся), как легко баги в нём исправлять, добавлять новую функциональность, не поломав его, насколько он производителен для вашей задачи.

Comment: @jfs со мной вы обсуждали. И я спрашивал вас абсолютно не java-специфичные вещи. Разговор был о принципах построения дизайна "когда все на контрактах, а детали реализации скрыты, тем самым обеспечивается низкая связанность (ООП+DI) и как с этим быть в питоне, в котором модуль - базовая единица и прямое обращениу к модулю, чтобы и чужеродной идеологии не было, но и потом в один момент не переписывать на классы". Автор вопрос о том же спрашивает, только не так углубленно как я (я давал конкретный пример). Но, увы, вы моих вопросов не поняли и ваши ответы по факту были бесполезны.

Comment: @vitidev: да, не удалось мне до вас достучаться, если вы такие вещи как *"необходимость пихать все в один файл модуль"* про Питон пишите.

Comment: @jfs сложно достучаться когда на прямые вопросы ответы в стиле "вот посмотрите парсер" или "вы не хотите учиться". Единственный ответ который удалось мне получить на мою абстрактную задачу был "если надо переписать, то берем и переписываем каждый раз". Ну это мы опять  в бесполезный спор уйдем. А про модули вы путаете понятия "рекомендует" и "заставляет".

Comment: @vitidev: мои комментарии не столько для вас сколько для других людей, чтобы вы их в заблуждение не вводили. Я привёл прямую цитату из вашего комментария. Если вы не хотите учиться Python package пользоваться—ваше дело. Это не какой-то экзотический материал—[модули в вводном руководстве описаны](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Если вопрос о flask, то и спрашивайте о flask о конкурентном приложении. Если вас абстрактно интересует как можно flask приложение по нескольким модулям разнести, то начните с официальной документации: [Larger Applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/patterns/packages/)—фактические приложения могут разную структуру иметь (следует из слова [microframework](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/foreword/#what-does-micro-mean)). Вообще, если не хотите выбирать, то используйте full stack framework такую как Django, где за вас большинство решений по организации структуры уже принято.

Comment: @jfs причем тут Python package . Вы на вопрос посмотрите - речь идет о организации дизайна кода в python стиле, которые понятно как организовываются в ооп языках, но непонятно как в питоне (никто не запрещает замутить такой же ооп, но хочется познать питон путь).. В моем диалоге с вами было то же самое (речь шла не о модулях, а о подходах к организации кода) я привел пример задачи и пример решения ее в чистом ооп стиле и спросил " а на питоне если модулями то как правильнее?". Наш чат никуда не делся, из вас просто плохой учитель  - вы не слушаете вопросы.

Comment: @vitidev: Python package имеет отношение как к вашему ошибочному комментарию про *"все в один файл модуль"* так и к вопросу автора. Прочтите первое предложение в ссылке выше: _"For larger applications it’s a good idea to use a **package** instead of a module."_ (выделение моё). Я могу только путь указать, а идти по нему (кликнуть на ссылку, прочитать, попробовать, итд) это уже от вас зависит. Если у вас нет ничего конструктивного сказать, то прошу больше *мне* комментарии не оставлять. Про корректность ваших последующих комментариев на этот вопрос, я предоставлю людям самостоятельно судить.

Comment: @jfs Сказать что есть, причем *по теме* вопроса, а именно вопросы "когда использовать классы, а когда модули?.  А как решать модулями то что в ооп решается вот так? Какие подходы можно применить в питоне вместо вот такого паттерна в ооп? Как управлять изменениями чтобы меньше переписывать? (В ООП это SOLID+GoF)". Эти вопросы согласуются с вопросом автора текущего вопроса (пока он про flask не добавил) и *не имеют никакого отношения* к python package.  Но вам нечего ответить на мои вопросы, поэтому да, больше с вами диалог вести не буду.

Comment: @vitidev прекратите писать мне сообщения. Если у вас есть конкретный вопрос, подходящий для Stack Overflow, см. [ask].

Comment: @vitidev я думаю, что `Python` просто не предназначен для больших проектов и заточен под небольшие блоги, сайты, парсеры.

Comment: @faoxis Не в этом дело. Просто модулеориентированность питона (вытягивание зависимостей) ведет к "конфиго-ориентированному" дизайну, что для скриптования не проблема, а для бОльших вещей придется учитывать эту особенность и, либо прибегать к магии, либо переписывать изменяемую часть. конфиго-ориентированность непривычна стороннику ооп, ведь он сразу думает "а что если вот эту часть придется заменять, а давай ка я тут инверсию зависимостей". Если же об этом не думать, пока не придет нужда, то можно писать.

Comment: @vitidev, хороший ответ. Жаль, что не вовремя. До меня уже дошло это уже когда я уже начал программировать почти только на `java`. :) На `python` просто не надо писать большие проекты и все будет в норме. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Избегать обычных функций точно не надо. Есть мнение что в питоне нет смысла, например, использовать статические методы, так как стиль будет более качественным если вместо них использовать функции.

Но в питоне никто ничего не навязывает. Есть модули для констант и для перечисляемых типов во встроенной библиотеке. Я например enum всегда использую где надо, просто для собственного успокоения. Да о чём речь? Добавить функционала для класса удобнее чем для списка констант.

То есть хочется в чистом-чистом ооп писать, да ради бога, есть всё необходимое для этого.

Comment: осталось выяснить, что такое "чистое-чистое ооп".

Comment: @KoVadim  это когда пишешь классы, даже если они используются в одном экземпляре.

Comment: Алан Кей [негодует](https://habrahabr.ru/company/hexlet/blog/303754/) по поводу Вашего объяснения. Скажем по простому -класс на каждый чих - это жава, а не ооп.

Comment: @KoVadim жава это язык, а ооп это принцип дизайна кода. Я ничего не говорил про "каждый чих", а говорил что то, что можно написать модулем (все равно будет единственный экземпляр), все равно пишешь как класс. Потому что а) контракт б) гибкость. Контракт....я могу собрать нужный граф объектов и подменить любой из них, потому что зависимости _пропихиваются_ в конструктор и соблюдают контракт . Гибкость....класс WebClient где можно задать хидеры вместо requests,get где нужно постоянно эти хидеры как параметр таскать.

Comment: Вы не поняли. Возможно ооп без классов и классы без ооп.

Comment: @KoVadim тем не менее питон вводит в ступор того, кто привык писать в описанном мной стиле. Это и необходимость пихать все в один файл модуль (отношение к модулю как к неймспейсу...хотя это модуль, что нечто иное) и вот такие вот статьи https://habrahabr.ru/post/140581/ и вообще тенденция все писать модулями. причем питонисту даже сложно пояснить проблему, я пробовал.

Comment: @vitidev не существует необходимости всё в один модуль пихать—не придумывайте (вероятно, мы это уже обсуждали). Из Zen of Python: "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!" (модуль это один из механизмов namespace в Питоне создать).

Comment: @jfs признаю ошибку. хотел написать "есть необходимость пихать все, что должно быть в модуле (не путать с package) в один файл"

Comment: @vitidev package это  модуль, у которого `__path__` выставлен. Даже тип идентичен. Если вам надо модуль на несколько файлов раскидать, то используйте Python package. Можно даже по разным директориям раскидать (namespace package). Можно (но не рекомендую) импортировать модули на лету из сети. Вот посмотрите на [некоторые примеры "интересных"  модулей](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/518371/23044)

Comment: @jfs Можно. Только это уже магия, а магия осложняет понимание. Я ж не говорю, что система модулей плохая - она отличная. Просто непривычна тем, кто приходит из языков где привычно "один класс на файл" - жава, шарп, даже пхп и разбиение на файлы и есть "тащим чужие подходы куда не надо". Я лично запихаю несколько классов в один файл, нежели буду разруливать другими механизмами. Это "необходимое зло" позволяет иметь ясность что и где.

Comment: @vitidev пакеты это не магия, а обычный скучный способ организовать код в Питоне.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос примером. Не могли бы вы его прокоментировать (интересно мнение обоих сторон) ?

Comment: Я не знаю, что там во фласке. Пользуюсь джангой, как обработчики запроса использую функции, в которые выношу очень абстрактные действия. Да, в джанге есть и CBV также. Иногда и они очень удобны, особенно тем, кто хорошо эту самую джангу знает, и часто пользуется.

Comment: То есть для многократного использования, конечно CBV(class-based views), намного удобнее.

Comment: В моей фирме запрещают пользоваться `Django`. Говорят, что это слишком перегруженный фреймворк. Слишком много всего ненужного якобы.