# Импорт модулей в уже запущенном приложении из подкаталогов

Tags: python, python-import

Имеется каталог modules с пустым файлом `__init__.py` и подкаталогами с `__init__.py` в каждом. Я не могу сразу сделать явный импорт при разработке приложения, т.к. не знаю как будут называть подкаталоги. Как сделать импорт модулей в уже запущенном приложении из подкаталогов?

```
+--+modules
    +
    +--+__init__.py
    |
    +--+unknown2
    |   +
    |   +--+__init__.py
    |
    +--+unknown3
    |   +
    |   +--+__init__.py
    |
    +--+unknown1
        |
        +--+__init__.py
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Можно ли загрузить содержимое модулей пакета, если `__init__` пуст?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/518371/23044)

Comment: Расскажите какой контекст у задачи. Почему вам приходится импортировать модули с неизвестными именами?

Comment: К примеру имеется приложение с подключением плагинов в виде отдельных модулей-каталогов.

Comment: @RemiZOffAlex можно убрать ограничение на то чтобы все плагины в одной директории были (позволяя их независимо разрабатывать/устанавливать), используя [setuptools entrypoints](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#entry-points). Велосипед изобретать не надо, но Питон сам по себе достаточно динамичный и pkgutil.iter_modules() может быть достаточно в вашем случае.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы импортировать все дочерние модули из `modules` пакета:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pkgutil
import modules

for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(modules.__path__):
    # import a module given its name and the importer
    module = importer.find_module(modname).load_module()
    assert module.__name__ == modname
```