# Как найти местоположение модуля Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Скрипт на Python использует некий модуль. С помощью какой команды можно найти его местоположение на диске машины?

Comment: find . -name "нейкий модуль"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module.__file__
```

В общем случае, модуль на Питоне не обязан быть в файле на диске. Модуль может быть в zip-архиве, налету создаваться.

В зависимости от того зачем вам нужен путь к модулю, есть разные API (наивный обход директорий из `sys.path` не нужен и может быть недостаточным). К примеру: [Можно ли загрузить содержимое модулей пакета, если `__init__` пуст?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/518371/23044) или чтобы ресурсы получить, лежащие в  директории с модулем: [Текущая директория в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044).

Answer (score 6):

```
import some_module
import sys
import os
for path in sys.path:
   if os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, 'some_module')):
      print('some_module is here: {}'.format(path))
```

"Трюк" здесь заключается в том, что где бы интерпретатор не встретил строку

```
from somewhere import something
```

он ищет `somewhere` в `sys.path`. И если не находит - выбрасывается исключение `ImportError`. При этом при запуске интерпретатора, текущий путь (или при запуске скрипта `python path/to/script.py` путь `path/to`) добавляется в `sys.path`.

2-й вариант (попроще):

```
import some_module
print(some_module.__file__)

>>> import openpyxl
>>> print (openpyxl.__file__)
D:\Python\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.3.0_b1-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\__init__.pyc
>>>
```

Но 2-й вариант можно "обмануть", явно определив в модуле переменную `__file__`

Comment: Первый вариант не сработает с кастомным модулем, если он не добавлен в `sys.path`. **_Чтобы добавить модуль в `sys.path` см `sys.path.append`_**

Comment: @KitScribe если модуль не добавлен в `sys.path`, он не за`import`ится)), В этом, собственно, и состоит идея.

Comment: Заимпортится, если будет в одной папке с импортируемым модулем, например) Или если в каталогах рядом: например есть подкаталог `SubPath`, в нём нужный модуль. `from SubPath import modulename`. В `sys.path` этот путь добавлен не будет.

Comment: @KitScribe и опять не совсем верно)) `'.'` - входит в `sys.path`. А в конструкции `from Path`.Path2 import module` нам надо искать `Path1/Path2`, который опять же должен быть в `sys.path`

Comment: Давай проведём эксперимент? У меня есть модуль по адресу `/media/username/diskname/PythonProjects/ForTest/test.py`. В папке `ForTest` есть ещё одна папка - `SomePath`, в которой лежит модуль `test2.py`. Пишем в модуле `test.py` первый вариант, изменяем под себя и импортируем `test2`: `from SomePath import test2`, запускаем `test.py` и ничего не получаем