# module 'math' has no attribute '__file__'

Tags: python

Хочу узнать расположение библеотеки math, но этот код не работает. Я полный ноль в ООП, так что можете объяснить, что мне делать на простом языке.

```
import math
print(math.__file__)
```

Вылетает ошибка
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\azizo\PycharmProjects\SF\z.py", line 2, in 
print(math.**file**)
AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute '**file**'

Comment: Не тот модуль выбрали для теста. `math` - built-in. Для него `__file__` не сработает.

Comment: А как тогда узнать расположение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модуль `math` не имеет исходников `python` на вашем ПК.
Этот модуль встроен в исполняемый файл интерпретатора, так как он является оберткой над `C` модулем `math`.
Если вам нужны исходники:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/cmathmodule.c

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут есть ответ - [Как найти местоположение модуля Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657406/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F-python)

можно еще почитать, например - https://otus.ru/nest/post/951/

всё это гуглится за пол минуты...